# Session Management in different browsers

Tags: java, session

I have deployed my web application on Tomcat7. There is a form asking some info and starts deploying another application and shows a progress bar and after completion redirects you to the new url.

If in the middle of deployment I close the tab or go to another url and then comes back to my application then I got new form instead of previous page showing my progress.This is happening in chrome and IE, while in Mozilla FirFox things are going perfect.

My question is that can some body tell me what is actually going on in those browsers and what I have to do to tackle this problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may the reason be in the approach those browsers work with tabs? every new tab for GC is a new system process...